# Java and Dates (Unparseable date)

Tags: java, date, grails

I can not make the issue of the date go ... I was looking at other posts but none ended up giving me results.

I receive the date as follows in AngularJS:

```
2019-05-04T09:00:00Z
```

And from Grails I handle it in the following way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX");
            Date d = sdf.parse(parametros.volverallamar);
```

But when trying to save it I receive the following error:

```
Unparseable date: "2019-05-03T09:00:00Z". Stacktrace follows:
```

THANKS!

Comment: Where's the `.SSSSSSSX` part of the date string? Also note that `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't handle fractions of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a date format with milliseconds (`.SSSSSSS`) but your actual input date does not have them.

Use a format without:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date d = sdf.parse("2019-05-04T09:00:00Z");
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using java 8 try it:

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2019-05-03T09:00:00Z", inputFormatter);
    String formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```